# c# wpf getting input from textbox in dynamically generated DataTemplate objects

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I'm a newcomer to C# WPF programming, and I'm having difficulty (spent a whole day on this) figuring out how to create a system where:

1) A collection of UI elements (in a groupbox) is generated with a click of a button.

2) The groupbox has a textbox (for int inputs) and a combobox (selection among strings). I need to populate combobox with the elements of a list. 
I need to take input from the textbox and selection from combobox and place it in a List of my structs Rules{ String topic; int number}.

This needs to be done for as many of the groupboxes the user generates.

The main question I have is, how do I access these comboboxes to populate them? How Do i get input from them?

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ExamMaker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExamMaker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Exam Preparation" Height="350" Width="525"
        Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ruleTemplate">
            <GroupBox x:Name="Rulebox" Header="Rule " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="468">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment = "Left" Height="36" Margin="0,0,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="458">
                    <Label x:Name="TopicRuleLabel" Content="Topic:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="NumberRuleTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="240,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="RuleComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                    <Label x:Name="NumberRuleLabel" Content="Number:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28"/>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
            <TabItem Header="Exam Preparation">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=examQS}">
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ruleTemplate}">

                        </ContentControl>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Question Form" Margin="-2,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="95">

            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Setup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54">

            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As for the c#, well I only have one Observable collection in there and some methods for adding and removing items from it.

Comment: To do this 'the right way' you'll want to look into the Model-View-ViewModel architectural pattern. This problem is solved in WPF by creating a ViewModel type that represents the thing you have a template for. Communication between ViewModels is often handled using a messaging pattern like Event Aggregation.

Comment: I did some reading on that, but unfortunately I find myself in crunch mode to put out a prototype as soon as possible. I am though going to get down to making it properly once a rough prototype is ready. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on what I see, I think here is how you can go about this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=examQS}"
```

assuming you have property ObservableCollectionexamQS 
1. Define a property in examQs lets say "comboItemSource"

2. change this line in your DataTemplate by adding a binding on ItemSource:     `<ComboBox x:Name="RuleComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemSource="{Binding Path=comboItemSource} />`
3. Change to use ItemTemplate

   `<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=examQS}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ruleTemplate}"/>`

I think the above should work.

Comment: Where is comboItemSource defined? In the ObservableCollection itself or in the Type of the elements the ObservableCollection contains?

Comment: If the first, then pardon me for asking (very new at this) but how is that done? What type is comboItemSource?